# Android facebook graph api add place or location params with photo upload

Tags: android, facebook

How can I send the place params while uploading a photo from android to facebook.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

params.putByteArray("photo", byteArray);

params.putString("caption", "FbAPIs Sample App photo upload");

//params.putString("place", "Banglore");

//params.putString("location", "banglore");

Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
    new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the place to the params, much like you did the caption.

```
params.putString("place","someLocation");
```

Comment: Pearsonartphoto thanks for replay its showing **bold**unknow error**bold** if add params.putString("place","someLocation");

Comment: i was using the hackbook "http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/hackbook/" i have sent caption and image sucess fully but the place is not updating in the facebook

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. Instead of using "Bangalore" for example, pass in the Facebook place ID.

Ex:

```
params.putString("place", "106377336067638");
```

For reference, see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

Comment: But how can i get the place ID dynamically while uploading?